# If $L:\mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^m$ and $m<n$ linear trans. What does this tell about injectivity and surjectivity?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Let $L:\mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^m$ be a linear transformation such that $m<n$. What does this tell you about injectivity and surjectivity?

I can't really create a (counter) argument against any of these alternatives:

- $L$ is injective
- $L$ is surjective
- $L$ is not injective
- $L$ is not surjective

My intuition says that one *could* find examples where $L$ is both injective and/or surjective, but not for all inputs outputs.

Comment: Those sets are equinumerous (same cardinality, assuming $m>0$), so there is a bijection between them. You can obviously get a surjection that is not an injection and a non-surjection (map everything to zero). Imposing continuity or linearity changes things, though.

Comment: Is $L$ an arbitrary function or a linear transformation?

Comment: Presumably, $L$ is a linear function?

Comment: Please clarify if $L$ is linear or a general map.

Comment: Sorry, updated now, yes L is a linear transformation.

Comment: If $L:\mathbb{R}^{3} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{2}$ and is defined as $L(x_{1},x_{2}) = x_{1}$ then we see that it is not injective right @Void

Comment: It is surjective.

Comment: @Alephnull. Not necessarily. It can for example be the zero homomorphism, which is not surjective if $m\gt0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remember that $\dim \operatorname{im}(L) + \dim\ker(L) = n$. Now, since $im(L)$ is a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^m$, its dimension is at most $m$. What can you conclude about the kernel?

Comment: Right, that would mean that $dim(ker (L)) > 0$ which means that there are infinite solutions for $ker(L)$ which means it's not injective. Am I understanding this correctly?

Comment: Exactly. Injectivity is equivalent to kernel consisting only of a zero vector.

Answer (score 1):

The key here is the [Rank-Nullity Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rank%E2%80%93nullity_theorem). It says that
$$\dim[\operatorname{im}L]+\dim[\ker L] = n$$

Since $\dim[\operatorname{im} L] \le m$ it follows that $\dim[\ker L] \ge n-m$. If $m<n$ then $n-m>0$ and so $\dim[\ker L] > 0$, meaning that $\ker L$ is non-trivial, i.e. there is $k \neq 0$ with $L(k)=0$.

If $0 \neq k \in \ker L$ then $L(v+k)=L(v)+L(k)=L(v)+0=L(v)$ for all $v \in \mathbb R^n$. This means that $L$ cannot be injective since $L(v+k)=L(v)$ but $v+k \neq v$.

Answer (score 1):

If L is linear then it is determined by where does it send the basis of $\mathbb{R}^n$ if you have that $m<n$ then it can't be an isomorphism because you can't take $n$ linearly independent vectors in $\mathbb{R}^m $ and then $L $ cannot be injective and onto at the same time.

Now check that if $L (v)  =0$ for every $v \in \mathbb{R}^n$ then L is not injectuve not surjective..
Now we can see it cannot be injective, $L $, take $v_1 , v_2 , \dots , v_n $ basis of $ \mathbb{R}^n$ then rename them so that $f (v_1), f (v_2), \dots , f (v_m) $ are the ones linearly independent, now $f (v _m+1)$ is spanned by a linear combination of the linearly independent ones and you can see two elements of $\mathbb{R}^n$ go to the same element of $\mathbb{R}^m $.

L actually can be surjective, take the cannonical projection for example.

Answer (score 1):

L is not injective because then it would restrict to an isomorphism onto a lower-dimensional space. L may be surjective (consider the projection map) but may not be (consider the projection onto R^0, R^1).